# Is this object reinitialization via explicit constructor and destructor calls technically correct?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I put a single local variable through two object life cycles:

```
class Thing
{
    int i;

public:
    Thing() : i(44) {}
    ~Thing() { i = 0; }
    void set(int i) { this->i = i; }
    void report() const { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};
```

...

```
Thing thing;
thing.report();
thing.set(72);
thing.report();
thing.~Thing();

new (&thing) Thing();
thing.report();
thing.set(97);
thing.report();
thing.~Thing();

thing.report();
```

I tentatively expect this to print the following:

```
44
72
44
97
0
```

And so it does.

But is this code guaranteed to work like that?  Or does it invoke undefined behavior or some such?  (I'm especially suspicious of the last `report()` call; I only threw that one in out of curiosity.)

Also what if the thing is a member:

```
struct Owner
{
    Thing thing;

    void go()
    {
        thing.report();
        thing.~Thing();

        new (&thing) Thing();
        thing.report();
    }
};
```

...

```
Owner owner;
owner.go();
Owner().go();
```

This also seems to work for me.  Should it?

(Yeah I know this technique is dangerous in various ways.  I'm not trying to ask or say anything about whether anybody should ever use it.  I just want to know whether it's really allowed by the standard, rather than merely being allowed by my current compiler setup.)

Comment: It was once upon a time a recommended way to write assignment operator, until the concern of exception safety came up.

Comment: Because `thing` was auto-constructed first, the destructor will be called automatically when its scope ends, so the last explicit destructor call (`thing.~Thing();`) should be skipped.  `new (&thing) Thing();` is using something called "placement new" on the object's original stack-allocated memory.  This acts as an explicit constructor call, allowing you to specify where the object's memory is located.  `Owner().go();` calls a member function on a temporary object.